# PgAdmin Not displaying boolean column values

Tags: boolean, pgadmin-4

In pgAdmin, I am unable to see the column values of the boolean column type.

```
SELECT is_adverse FROM my_table;
```

[image]

```
SELECT is_adverse::TEXT FROM my_table;
```

[image]

I was not getting this problem earlier. This is pgAdmin4. Known issue? or any configuration to get this resolved. It has become difficult have a quick view at all the row values of all the boolean columns.

Comment: As well as I remember, there was magic "Expand" link somewhere in the bottom of the table...

Comment: Please upgrade to latest version of pgAdmin4 (1.6), I am not able to re-produce the issue on this version. Screenshot: https://ibb.co/djO8VQ

Comment: ok. thanks. Will upgrade. Not sure what's the issue. The bug is not consistent across all tables. Only for the newly added column of this table. Presently pgAdmin4 1.4.

Comment: @stanislav not found